# List items created when the user clicks on 'Enter' button not crossing out

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a list where the user can add their own items to it by typing in a text box and pressing the Enter key or clicking on the "Enter" button. I'm trying to get the list items to get crossed out when the user clicks on them but this doesn't seem to work on list items created by the user, it only works on list items added in the HTML file.

Shouldn't `crossBTNs()` work on user generated list items too? Sorry if this is a basic question, I'm new to JS.

EDIT: Figured it out
I simply did this:

```
li.addEventListener("click", function () {
crossOutUserItem(li); });
```

I added this code to `createListElement()`. `crossOutUserItem(li)` adds the class that creates the "crossed out" effect to the list item.

Original code:

```
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");

function createListElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.append(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  input.value = "";
}

function addListAfterClick() {
  if (input.value.length > 0) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

function addListAfterKeypress(event) {
  if (input.value.length > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

function crossBTNs () {
    for (let i = 0; i < ul.children.length; i++) {
      ul.children[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        ul.children[i].classList.toggle("crossOut");
      });
    }
}

button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);

input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);

crossBTNs();
```

Comment: You're adding event listeners to the existing `li` elements. You can use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to make sure the click events on dynamically added elements work as well.

Answer (score 1):

By adding event handlers on the `li`, as you have done.

```
function crossBTNs () {
    for (let i = 0; i < ul.children.length; i++) {
      ul.children[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        ul.children[i].classList.toggle("crossOut");
      });
    }
}
```

It doesn't set any event handler for the list items `li` which are generated dynamically, because as the js file loads the handlers are set initially only.

You will need to use `event delegation` in which you set the handler on the parent of `li`, which is `ul` and look for the particular child element from where the event has actually happened using `e.target` properties as per your requirement.

You can use this resource [MDN Docs Event Delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) to know more about `event delegation` in javascript.

Comment: So show that instead of only linking to it?

Comment: @mplungjan OP had not provided HTML, I thought They will learn more if they give it a try. Anyways, next time on wards I'll surely provide code as well :-)  Hope you are doing good SIR.?

Comment: I am well. Getting very cold here. Tomorrow snow storm. And you?

Comment: I am also fine Thank you :-) It is better here especially after February . It was snowy here also before that. Stay safe Sir :)

Answer (score 1):

Just [delegate from the closest static container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) - likely the UL in this case.

```
ul.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("li");
  tgt.classList.toggle("crossOut");
});
```

Now you can remove all other event handling for the LI and do not need to call something after adding an LI to add event handling